# SonarQube UI rendering delay (exactly 1 minute!)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I installed [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/) to help with code quality analysis. I set it up to run behind an Nginx reverse proxy using the [instructions on their website](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy). Often I have to wait exactly one minute to load a page. Upon investigation using Google Chrome Developer Tools, I saw that a resource was not loading for exactly one minute. Then, **something** times out and allows the page to continue to load. Here's a typical example of the problem, where some resources load at the beginning, then there's a one minute delay, then the rest of the page loads:

[image: Typical delay]

Sometimes the page loads without any delay.

At first I thought it might be a problem with some JavaScript. Here is an example of clicking around to many pages, and sorting by response time (to see resources might be causing the delay):

[image: Many page loads]

I then tried loading a static image, and even that intermittently takes a minute to load.

[image: Intermittent long loads for logo]

How can I pin down exactly what component is causing the delay? Could it be the reverse proxy? The SonarQube application? Some JVM problem?

Answer (score 1):

As your 1mn delay happen also with static image (here logo), where there is minimal JVM impact, I would suggest to use curl -L -v against Nginx front end and also directly to SQ HTTP connector.

If 1mn delay never happen when connection to SQ HTTP connector, Nginx / SQ link should be investigated.

If 1mn delay happen also with SQ HTTP connector, SQ JVMs and hosting should be investigated